# Get last sequence of String and cut everything off whats before

Tags: php, string

Given this string: `"hal today is a beatiful weather hal whats going on hal super"` I want to get everything after the last char sequence of "hal". In this case: `"super"`

This little line already cuts off everything after the first `"hal"`:

```
$whatIWant = substr($string, strpos($string, "hal ") + 4);
```

However I have no clue how to achieve it that, it just takes the last `"hal "`.

Comment: Just use `strrpos` in place of `strpos`

Comment: @Saty nice ty :)

Comment: Just to know... Do you want a generic function or something for that case?

Comment: substr_count ? [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.substr-count.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use `strrpos` to get the last position:

```
$string = "hal today is a beatiful weather hal whats going on hal super";
print $whatIWant = substr($string, strrpos($string, "hal ") + 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
$arr = explode('hal ', $your_string);
$result = $arr[1];
```

Comment: This won't work correctly if "`hal`" appears more than once in the string.

Comment: Then let them do `$result = array_pop($arr);` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php) to split the string with a delimiter to an array and take the last array entry.

```
$delimiter = "hal";
$text = "hal today is a beatiful weather hal whats going on hal super";
$arr = explode($delimiter, $text);
if count($arr) > 0) {
    $result = $arr[count($arr) - 1)];
} else {
    $result = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php), and [`end`](http://php.net/manual/function.end.php)

```
// the string you want to scan
$text = "hal today is a beatiful weather hal whats going on hal super";

// get an array containing sequences after each "hal"
$sequences = explode("hal", $s);

// get the last sequence
$last_seq = end($e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for generic purpose.

```
function getLast($string, $neddle) {
    $last = strrpos($string, $neddle);
    return $last === false ? "" : substr($string, $last + strlen($neddle));
}
$string = "hal today is a beatiful weather hal whats going on hal super";
print getLast($string, "hal ");
```

## Please note that you'll need to include that white space!

Answer (score 0):

**I think its work you could be try this**

```
$stringdata = 'hal today is a beatiful weather hal whats going on hal super';

$substringdata = 'hal';

echo substr($stringdata, strpos($stringdata, $substringdata)+strlen($substringdata)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last segment after explode input string by `hal`. Or use regular expression to extract your content:

```
$input = 'hal today is a beatiful weather hal whats going on hal super';

// Using explode
$output = @trim(end(explode('hal', $input))); // 'super'

// Or using regular expression
$output = preg_replace('/^.*hal\s*(.*)$/', '$1', $input); // 'super'
```